# What is parent.result.location

Tags: javascript, html

Can somebody please explain to me what the following is:

```
parent.result.location
```

Is it an ajax call? If it is an ajax call, POST or get
what is the use of this call, instead of making direct ajax call?

Here, i am providing sample code

```
<select onchange="dropdownChange(this.value);" id="selA1">
      <option value="0">- Please Select -</option>   
      <option value="1">option1</option>
      <option value="2">option2</option>    
      <option value="3">option3</option> 
</select>

<script> 
function dropdownChange(theSelected) {
    parent.result.location = "/Controller?formname=A1_TAB_FORM&action=action1&val="theSelected"; 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Where did you see this? Is it part of some larger javascript somewhere?

Comment: It would seem to be a reference to an object called `parent` (possibly `window.parent`?) that has a property called `result` that in turn has a property called `location`. It's not a function _call_ but could be a reference to a function. Why do you think it has anything to do with Ajax? Taken out of context it could mean anything, so how 'bout you provide an example of how you've seen it used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well its used for frames. For example, lets say you a page as:

```
<frameset>
  <frame src="first.html" />
  <frame name="result" src="second.html" />
</frameset>
```

And you want to refresh **second.html** page from **first.html**. Then in your **first.html** page, yo can do something like:

```
function refresh() { parent.result.location.reload(); }
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="refresh()">
```

Hope it helps in some way

Comment: thank u sudhir. But, if i want to avoid avoid parent.result.location = "some url" and if i use ajax call, i am not getting any response. Can it be possible to change to ajax call. Is it make sense atleast?